# Найти исходники минифицированного js-файла

Tags: минификация

К сайту подключен минифицированный файл с js-кодом. Минифицирован скорее всего через Uglifyjs.

Мне нужно его отредактировать, но я не могу найти исходники, а работать с текущим без знания имен переменных и функций не представляется возможным. Найти разработчика, чтобы связаться с ним, не удается и вряд ли получится.

Читала, что в этом может помочь source map, но как им воспользоваться пока так и не поняла.

Буду благодарна за помощь и любые подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто столкнулся с подобным вопросом: мне помогло открыть веб-страницу в браузере Microsoft Edge и через "Прослушиватель событий" в Developer Tools увидеть исходный js-файл. Всего то :)